# .net Membership provider programmatically create application

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I see the stored procedure "aspnet_Applications_CreateApplications"
What C# method would allow me to run this programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure `aspnet_Applications_CreateApplications` is used by several of the sql providers in ASP.Net, such as the Membership, Role, and Personalization providers. But the procedure is not actually called through C# code. Instead this procedure is called by other procedures. For example:

In the Sql Membership Provider, when you call the CreateUser method:

1. The method calls the `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` procedure
2. The above rcedure then calls the `aspnet_Applications_CreateApplications` procedure

Thus, you will have to write your own code to connect to the database and call this procedure.

Comment: So basically just create a user and it'll do it for you.

Comment: @Greg Exactly. When using the membership provider, creating a user with the CreatUser method or using the create user wizard control will automatically call the aspnet_Applications_CreateApplication stores procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIC, the ASP.NET provide no direct interface to this functionality through it's membership library.

Short of using ADO.NET to invoke the procedure directly, I'm not sure how you can use this functionality.

Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a web service handler that creates applications.
I just used SubSonic 2.2 to generat a DAL and that made a nice SP wrapper. Do this works for me.
Now I wonder that is the cleanest way to delete an application?